# i want to save data using following c# code but its not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i want to upload two pic and one file and other data using asp.net with following c#.but it giving  error of Uploadresumepic.SaveAs(path1);

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class resume_add : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JOBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    string f1;
    string f2;
    string f3;
    string path1;
    string path2;
    string path3;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void submitresumebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {

            if (Uploadresumepic.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                f1 = Path.GetFileName(Uploadresumepic.FileName);
                path1 = Server.MapPath("profile_pic") + "/" + f1;
                Uploadresumepic.SaveAs(path1);
            }
            if (FileUploadresumefile.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                f2 = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadresumefile.FileName);
                path2 = Server.MapPath("resume_file") + "/" + f2;
                FileUploadresumefile.SaveAs(path2);
            }
            if (coverimage.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                f3 = Path.GetFileName(coverimage.FileName);
                path3 = Server.MapPath("cover_image") + "/" + f3;
                coverimage.SaveAs(path3);
            }
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Recruiter_detail"))
            {

                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.Connection = con;
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profile_pic", f1);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextName.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@headline", TxtHedline.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@short_description", textdescription.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", TextBoxlocation.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@website_address", TextBoxadress.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", TextBoxsalary.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_no", TxtBoxphoneno.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resume_file", f2);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cover_image", f3);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facebook_Url", FbURL.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Twitter_Url", TwitterUrl.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@google_url", GoogleUrl.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@youtube_url", YoutubeUrl.Text.Trim());
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", TextBoxage.Text.Trim());
                    com.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }

                Lblsubmit.Text = "Resume Created";
            }

        }
    }
```

The sql create procedure i am using is:

```
USE [JOB]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Recruiter_detail]
    @profile_pic varchar(50),
    @name varchar(50),
    @headline nvarchar(50),
    @short_description nvarchar(50),
    @location nvarchar(50),
    @website_address nvarchar(50),
    @salary nvarchar(50),
    @phone_no nvarchar(50),
    @resume_file nvarchar(50),
    @cover_image nvarchar(50),
    @facebook_Url nvarchar(50),
    @Twitter_Url nvarchar(50),
    @google_url nvarchar(50),
    @youtube_url nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT Recruiter_id FROM Recruiter WHERE Username = '" + Session["name"] + "')
    BEGIN
        SELECT -1 
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Recruiter]
               ([profile_pic]
               ,[name]
               ,[headline]
               ,[short_description]
               ,[location]
               ,[website_address]
               ,[salary]
               ,[phone_no]
               ,[resume_file]
               ,[cover_image]
               ,[facebook_Url]
               ,[Twitter_Url]
               ,[google_url]
               ,[youtube_url]
               )
        VALUES
               (@profile_pic
               ,@name
               ,@headline
               ,@short_description
               ,@location
               ,@website_address
               ,@salary
               ,@phone_no
               ,@resume_file
               ,@cover_image
               ,@facebook_Url
               ,@Twitter_Url
               ,@google_url
               ,@youtube_url
               )


        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- Recruiter_id            
     END
END


GO
```

the following tags in aspx code i am using

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <asp:FileUpload ID="Uploadresumepic" type="file" class="dropify" data-default-file="assets/img/avatar.jpg" runat="server" />
                        <span class="help-block">Please choose a 4:6 profile picture.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextName" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtHedline" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Headline (e.g. Front-end developer)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="textdescription" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Short description about you" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="hr-lg">

                    <h6>Basic information</h6>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxlocation" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location, e.g. Melon Park, CA" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxadress" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxsalary" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Salary, e.g. 85" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Per hour</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i></span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxage" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Years old</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBoxphoneno" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxaddress" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>
<div class="button-group">
                <div class="action-buttons">

                    <div class="upload-button">
                        <button class="btn btn-block btn-gray">Choose a resume file</button>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadresumefile" type="file" runat="server" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="upload-button">
                        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Choose a cover image</button>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="coverimage" type="file" runat="server" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="FbURL" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Profile URL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="GoogleUrl" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Profile URL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TwitterUrl" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Profile URL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>





                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="YoutubeUrl" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Profile URL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<asp:Button ID="submitresumebtn" class="btn btn-success btn-xl btn-round" runat="server" Text="Submit your resume" OnClick="submitresumebtn_Click" />
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: "Giving error" does not give any clue. Edit your question and tell us what exact exception does it throws if any

Comment: There is no need to use using on SqlCommand, also when you use using on SqlConnection there is no need to Close it. Like other said for your other problem you need to provide exception.

Comment: debug your code step by step - to find the error that you have.... the database insert did not have to do with the error that you say... but you probably you have bugs there too.

Comment: the error showing is:                                                                             Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Mohsin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\JOB\profile_pic\mohsin.jpg'.                                                     Line 35:                 Uploadresumepic.SaveAs(path1);

Comment: i want to save files into sql server database not in a project subfolder.            plz guide me

Comment: i have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

just change the code to

```
path1 = Server.MapPath("~/profile_pic/" + f1);
```

Comment: it still showing the error:                                                                             Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Mohsin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\JOB\profile_pic\mohsin.jpg'.                                                     Line 35:                 Uploadresumepic.SaveAs(path1);                                                 i want to save files into database not in the project subfolder.